# Find a basis of $U = \{p \in \mathcal{P}_4(F):p(6)=0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

My answer is $(x-6), (x-6)^2, (x-6)^3, (x-6)^4$. I am not sure whether I am correct. I think they are inside $U$.

My thought was letting $x = 6$, they all become $0$. I am not sure whether the reasoning is correct. And they are linearly independent because they only way to make $a_0(x-6) + a_1(x-6)^2 + a_3(x-6)^3 + a_4(x-6)^4 = 0$ is by setting all $a's$ equal $0$.

In [this](http://linearalgebras.com/2c.html) ans, it said $(x-6), (x^2-6x), (x^3-6x^2), (x^4-6x^3)$ is the answer. I know that basis is not unique and there could be multiple answers. My question is then how he comes up with this basis?

Comment: Basically if $p(6) = 0$, then $6$ is a root. Hence $p(x)$ possesses a linear factor of $(x-6)$. So by degree argument, what must be left is a 3rd degree polynomial of the form $k_3x^3 + \dots +k_0$. Multiplying out gives the form you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are inside $U$ and they are independent.

Now, to check that they span $U$.

Suppose $y \in U$, then we can write \begin{align}y=(x-6)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=ax^3(x-6)+bx^2(x-6)+ cx(x-6) + d(x-6) \end{align}

Hence we can see that the dimension is $4$ and you (as well as the other answer) have found a basis.

Answer (score 1):

All polynomials in $U$ are divisible by $x-6,$ hence $U$ is isomorphic to $ \mathcal{P}_3(F),$ which has basis $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\};$ reverse the isomorphism.